camera2 apiでズーム機能を追加したい
onCreateのmMaxZoom = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM);からmCropRegion = activeRect;の範囲でエラーが起きてしまっています。主に不明なクラスというエラー文が出ます。どなたかご教授お願い致します。
package com.vuzix.sample.video_encoder;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaCodecList;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RotationListener.rotationCallbackFn{

    public static final String TAG = "MediaCodec_App";
    private Button mRecordButton;
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private String mCameraId;
    protected CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession mCameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;
    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private RotationListener mRotationListener;

    private Button wordButton;

    private boolean mRecognizerActive = false;

    public final String CUSTOM_SDK_INTENT = "com.vuzix.sample.vuzix_voicecontrolwithsdk.CustomIntent";
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundPreviewHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundPreviewThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundCodecHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundCodecThread;

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    // parameters for the encoder
    private static final int FRAME_RATE = 24;               // 24fps
    private static final int IFRAME_INTERVAL = 5;           // 5 seconds between I-frames
    private static final int MAX_QUEUE_ELEMENTS = 8;

    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";    // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
    private static final String ENCODER = "OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc"; // HW encoder
    //private static final String ENCODER = "OMX.google.h264.encoder";  // SW encoder

    private MediaCodec mEncoder;
    private MediaMuxer mMuxer;
    private MediaFormat mEncoderFormat = null;

    private LinkedList<byte[]> mBytesQueue;
    private final Object mBytesQueueLock = new Object();
    private int mQueueElementCount;

    private boolean mVideoRecording = false;
    private boolean mMuxerStarted;
    private boolean mCaptureSessionStopped;

    private int mTrackIndex;
    private long mFramesIndex;

    VoiceCmdReceiver mVoiceCmdReceiver;

    private MyIntentReceiver  myIntentReceiver;
    private View recordButton;

    // ズーム関連のフィールド
    private float mZoomLevel = 1.0f; // 現在のズームレベル
    private  float mMaxZoom = 1.0f; // カメラがサポートする最大ズーム
    private Rect mCropRegion; // ズームの適用範囲

    public MainActivity(CameraManager manager) throws CameraAccessException {
        this.manager = manager;
    }


    /**
     * Setup the view when created
     * @param savedInstanceState - unused, passed to superclass
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        openCamera();
        manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);


        mRecordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_record);
        wordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        mRecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecordOrStopClick();
            }
        });
        myIntentReceiver = new MyIntentReceiver();
        registerReceiver(myIntentReceiver , new IntentFilter(CUSTOM_SDK_INTENT), Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);

        mVoiceCmdReceiver = new VoiceCmdReceiver(this);


    }

    private CameraManager manager;
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
    mMaxZoom = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM);

    // カメラセンサーのサイズを取得
    Rect activeRect = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
    mCropRegion = activeRect;

    private void setZoom(float zoomLevel) {
        if (zoomLevel < 1.0f || zoomLevel > mMaxZoom) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid zoom level: " + zoomLevel);
            return; // ズーム範囲外は無視
        }

        mZoomLevel = zoomLevel;

        // センサーサイズを基にクロップ領域を計算
        Rect activeRect = mCropRegion;
        int cropWidth = (int) (activeRect.width() / mZoomLevel);
        int cropHeight = (int) (activeRect.height() / mZoomLevel);
        int cropX = (activeRect.width() - cropWidth) / 2;
        int cropY = (activeRect.height() - cropHeight) / 2;
        mCropRegion = new Rect(cropX, cropY, cropX + cropWidth, cropY + cropHeight);

        // リクエストに新しいクロップ領域を適用
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, mCropRegion);

        try {
            mCameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public String getMethodName() {
        return TAG + ":" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + new Throwable().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
    }

    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundPreviewThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Preview");
        mBackgroundPreviewThread.start();
        mBackgroundPreviewHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundPreviewThread.getLooper());

        //the thread to handle the captured images
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());

        //The thread to handle the images encoding
        mBackgroundCodecThread = new HandlerThread("Codec Thread");
        mBackgroundCodecThread.start();
        mBackgroundCodecHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundCodecThread.getLooper());
    }



    /**
     * Destroys background threads. Called when we pause
     */
    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundPreviewThread.quitSafely();
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        mBackgroundCodecThread.quitSafely();

        try {
            mBackgroundPreviewThread.join();
            mBackgroundPreviewThread = null;
            mBackgroundPreviewHandler = null;

            //the thread to handle the captured images
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;

            //The thread to handle the images encoding
            mBackgroundCodecThread.join();
            mBackgroundCodecThread = null;
            mBackgroundCodecHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start to record the video, setup the preview and video stream for camera
     * Setup the image reader to receive the captured images
     */
    protected void recordVideo() {
        if(null == mCameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "mCameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }

        try {
            final int encodeWidth =1280;        // record video size
            final int encodeHeight =720;       // record video size
            final int encodeBitRate = 6164000; // Mbps

            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>();
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(encodeWidth, encodeHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
            outputSurfaces.add(mImageReader.getSurface());

            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(640, 320); // preview size
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            outputSurfaces.add(previewSurface);

            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

                boolean first = true;

                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    if(image!=null){
                        ByteBuffer bufferY = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        ByteBuffer bufferU = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();

                        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferY.capacity() + bufferU.capacity()];
                        bufferY.get(bytes, 0, bufferY.capacity());
                        bufferU.get(bytes, bufferY.capacity(), bufferU.capacity());

                        synchronized (mBytesQueueLock) {
                            mBytesQueue.add(bytes);
                            mFramesIndex++;
                            mQueueElementCount++;

                            if (mQueueElementCount >= MAX_QUEUE_ELEMENTS) {
                                try {
                                    mBytesQueueLock.wait();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                mBytesQueueLock.notifyAll();
                            }
                        }

                        //begin to start encoder once receive the first captured image
                        if(first) {
                            first = false;
                            mBackgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    startEncoder();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        image.close();
                    }
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    mCameraCaptureSessions = session;
                    mCaptureSessionStopped = false;
                    //After the camera capture session is created, call prepare HW Encoder
                    prepareEncoder( encodeWidth, encodeHeight, encodeBitRate);
                    updatePreview();

                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onClosed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    synchronized (mBytesQueueLock) {
                        mCaptureSessionStopped = true;
                        mBytesQueueLock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }, mBackgroundPreviewHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Utility to prepare and configure the encoder parameters
     * Need to call startEncoder() once receive the first captured image in image reader
     *
     * @param width int width of the video image in pixels
     * @param height int height of the video image in pixels
     * @param bitRate int rate of the encoder in bits per second
     */
    private void prepareEncoder(int width, int height, int bitRate){

        mMuxerStarted = false;
        mTrackIndex = -1;
        mFramesIndex = 0;

        try {
            mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(getOutputMediaPath(width, height), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
            mMuxer.setOrientationHint(getImageRotationDegrees(false));

            mEncoderFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height);
            int colorFormat = selectColorFormat(Objects.requireNonNull(selectCodec()));

            mEncoderFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
                    colorFormat);
            mEncoderFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
            mEncoderFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
            mEncoderFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);

            mBytesQueue = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
            mQueueElementCount = 0;
            mEncoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(Objects.requireNonNull(selectCodec()).getName());

        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Utility to start the HW encoder,set the Callback to handle the input and output for the MediaCodec
     * This method need to be called once receive the first captured image in image reader
     */
    void startEncoder(){

        mEncoder.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void onOutputFormatChanged(MediaCodec codec,MediaFormat format) {

                if (mMuxerStarted) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("format changed twice");
                }

                MediaFormat newFormat = codec.getOutputFormat();
                Log.d(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat);

                mTrackIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                mMuxer.start();
                mMuxerStarted = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index) {

                long ptsUsec = computePresentationTime(mFramesIndex);
                byte[] inputBytes = null;

                synchronized (mBytesQueueLock) {
                    inputBytes = mBytesQueue.poll();
                    mQueueElementCount --;

                    if(mQueueElementCount == 0){
                        try {
                            mBytesQueueLock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(mQueueElementCount <0)
                            mQueueElementCount = 0;
                        mBytesQueueLock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }

                if( inputBytes != null && inputBytes.length > 0 && index >=0 ){
                    ByteBuffer input = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
                    input.clear();
                    input.put(inputBytes);
                    if(mCaptureSessionStopped){

                        codec.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, 0, ptsUsec, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    }else
                        codec.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, inputBytes.length, ptsUsec, 0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index, MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {

                if(!mMuxerStarted){
                    throw new RuntimeException("muxer hasn't started");
                }

                ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(index);

                if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                    // The codec config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer when we got
                    // the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  Ignore it.
                    Log.d(TAG, "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG");
                    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, false);
                    return;
                }
                if (info.size != 0) {
                    if(mMuxer!=null) {
                        outputBuffer.position(info.offset);
                        outputBuffer.limit(info.offset + info.size);

                        mMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, outputBuffer, info);
                        Log.d(TAG, "sent " + info.size + " bytes to muxer");
                    }
                }
                codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, false);
                if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "end of stream reached");
                    mMuxerStarted = false;
                    mCaptureSessionStopped = false;
                    releaseEncoder();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(MediaCodec codec, MediaCodec.CodecException e) {

            }
        }, mBackgroundCodecHandler);

        mEncoder.configure(mEncoderFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mEncoder.start();
    }


    private long computePresentationTime(long frameIndex) {
        return 132 + frameIndex * 1000000 / FRAME_RATE;
    }

    private String getOutputMediaPath(int width, int height){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "video_encoder");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "can not create the directory");
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        return (mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VIDEO_" +timeStamp+"_"+width +"x"+height + ".mp4").toString();
    }

    /**
     * Utility to converts the mime type string into a codec info class
     *
     * @return MediaCodecInfo matching selected mimeType, or null
     */
    private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec() {
        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);

            if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
                continue;
            }

            String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
            String codecName = codecInfo.getName();
            for (String type : types) {
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(MainActivity.MIME_TYPE) && codecName.equalsIgnoreCase(ENCODER)) {
                    return codecInfo;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static int selectColorFormat(MediaCodecInfo codecInfo) {
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(MainActivity.MIME_TYPE);
        for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length; i++) {
            int colorFormat = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
            if (isRecognizedFormat(colorFormat)) {
                return colorFormat;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "couldn't find a good color format for " + codecInfo.getName() + " / " + MainActivity.MIME_TYPE);
        return 0;   // not reached
    }

    /**
     * Utility to determine if the proposed color format is valid
     * @param colorFormat int candidate for a color format identifier
     * @return true if recognized as a valid format
     */
    private static boolean isRecognizedFormat(int colorFormat) {
        // these are the formats we know how to handle for this test
        return colorFormat == MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;
    }

    /**
     * Releases encoder resources.
     */
    public void releaseEncoder() {
        Log.d(TAG, "releasing encoder objects");

        if (mImageReader != null) {
            mImageReader.close();
            mImageReader = null;
        }

        if (mEncoder != null) {
            mEncoder.stop();
            mEncoder.release();
            mEncoder = null;
        }

        if (mMuxer != null) {
            mMuxer.stop();
            mMuxer.release();
            mMuxer = null;
        }

        mQueueElementCount = 0;
        mBytesQueue.clear();
    }


    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(1920, 1000);// preview size
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    mCameraCaptureSessions = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, mBackgroundPreviewHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens the camera for immediate preview
     */
    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            mCameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0]; // カメラIDを取得
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);

            // 最大ズーム倍率を取得
            mMaxZoom = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM);
            Log.d(TAG, "Max Zoom: " + mMaxZoom);

            // センサーのアクティブ領域を初期化
            mCropRegion = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);

            // カメラを開く
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(mCameraId, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                    mCameraDevice = camera;
                    createCameraPreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
                    camera.close();
                    mCameraDevice = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                    camera.close();
                    mCameraDevice = null;
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Updates the preview by providing an orientation and preview handler
     */
    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == mCameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        try {
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getImageRotationDegrees(false));
            mTextureView.setRotation(getImageRotationDegrees(true));
            mCameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRotationChanged(int newRotation) {
        Log.i(TAG, "New device orientation " + Integer.toString(newRotation) );
        updatePreview();
    }

    private int getImageRotationDegrees(boolean invert) {
        // The encoder operates upside-down by default.  So invert this.  Our display is only ROTATION_0 or ROTATION_180
        int rotation = 180;
        if ( ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
            rotation = 0;
        }
        if(invert) {
            if( 0 == rotation ) {
                rotation = 180;
            }
            else {
                rotation = 0;
            }
        }
        //Log.i(TAG, "Rotation " + Integer.toString(rotation) );
        return rotation;
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != mImageReader) {
            mImageReader.close();
            mImageReader = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);

        if(mTextureView.isAvailable()){
            openCamera();
        }

        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                openCamera();
            }
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            }
        });

    }




    public class MyIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e(TAG, getMethodName());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Custom Intent Detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!, you don't have permission to run this app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }


}


他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？
